# How to write a recursive method to promote a String to all possible combinations, With no loops or arrays?

Tags: java, recursion, passwords, combinations

```
public Password(int length)//a constructor that creates a random password in a given length
public boolean isPassword(String st)//retruns True if the String equals to the password.
```

I need to make a recursive method... to crack the password...
it contains only lower-case letters.
I can only use:
isPassword(),(charAt, equals, length, substring)
No loops, no arrays...

this is what ive done so far, i got an "a" String to the right length:

```
/**
 * Recursive method, cracks and return 
 * the right string of Password p.
 * @param p The Password object to crack.
 * @param length The length of the password.
 * @return The String combination of the password.
 */
public static String findPassword(Password p,int length)
{
    String aString;//to store an "aaa.." string in the length of p
    String password;//to store the password

    aString = findPassword("a",length);//recursion method, gets string of a in length
    password = findPassword(aString, p, 0);//recursion method, finds the password

    return password;
}
public static String findPassword(String startString, int length)
{   //recursion to make "aaa..." string in the length of n.
    if (startString.length() != length )//if not in the length
    {
        startString += "a";        //add "a" character
        if(startString.length() == length)//if in the length, 
        {                     //return String
            return startString;
        }
    }                  //call the recursion if still
    return findPassword(startString,length);//not in the length
}
```

Now I need to promote this string to all possible combinations... and I have no idea how to do so without loops or an array...
thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. First of all, you might want to take a look at the [How do I ask a good question?-page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Second, please reformat your question to highlight the codeblocks as such (indentation with four spaces should do the trick). You should share your solution(s) so far and ask more specific question, e.g. where exactly you are stuck. This way, we can give you more precise answers and explain the concepts you are struggling with.

Comment: Basically, what you need to implement is a counting function. The "numbers" you count is the password combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an answer for you.

The idea to crack a password is to run through all possible combinations. The combinations are basically a sequence like 1,2,3,4, ... (iIrc B-adic sequences is the term in math).

For a decimal sequence, you have digits 0-9 and the rule is to overflow to the next number if you reach the end of the alphabet (9 in this case).

The decimal counting system can be applied to anything: binary numbers have an alphabet of 2 (0,1). hex numbers have an alphabet of 16 (0-9,a-f).

The passwort you are looking for has an alphabet of the allowed character set in your password. The set is represented in an array of characters. The array defines the order and the size of the set. To iterate the passwords, you apply the counting algorithm to your password-"number".

The following code does this:

```
public class PasswordFinder {

    private static final String PASSWORD = "zxy";
    private static final char[] ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();

    boolean isPassword(String pass) {
        return (pass.equals(PASSWORD));
    }

    boolean findPassword(String password) {
        while (!isPassword(password)) {
            password = next(password);
        }
        return true;
    }

    /* recursive variant, will require up to (ALPHABET.length^(PASSWORD.length+1)) - 1 recursions */

    boolean findPasswordRecursive(String password) {
        if (isPassword(password)) {
            return true;
        }

        return findPasswordRecursive(next(password));
    }

    private String next(String password) {
        if( password.length() == 0 ) {
            return "" + ALPHABET[0];
        }

        char nextChar = password.charAt(password.length()-1);
        int idx = (nextChar - ALPHABET[0] + 1) % ALPHABET.length;
        if( idx == 0 ) {
            return next(password.substring(0, password.length() - 1)) + ALPHABET[0];
        }

        return password.substring(0, password.length() - 1) + ALPHABET[idx];
    }
}
```

The `next` function does the counting:

If we receive no password (you can apply a null check here as well), we create one with the first "digit" from our alphabet:

```
        if( password.length() == 0 ) {
            return "" + ALPHABET[0];
        }
```

We now select the char to be counted up. It is always the last digit of your sequence, the last char of the string:

```
        char nextChar = password.charAt(password.length()-1);
```

To count, we calculate the index of the char in the alphabet (index magic, substract the first char from the found char), the index is increased by 1. To handle the "end of alphabet", we use the modulo operator. It will return 0 when we reached the end of the alphabet.

```
        int idx = (nextChar - ALPHABET[0] + 1) % ALPHABET.length;
```

When we reach the end of the alphabet, we need to overflow to the next digit and add one to that: `"9" + 1 => "10"`. Since overflowing is recursive, we use our counting function to add one to each digit in the password and overflow accordingly. To do this, we add 1 to the prefix of the last digit and reset the last digit to "0": `"89" + 1 => next("8") + "0"`

```
        if( idx == 0 ) {
            return next(password.substring(0, password.length() - 1)) + ALPHABET[0];
        }
```

If we need not to overflow, we simply increase the last digit.

```
        return password.substring(0, password.length() - 1) + ALPHABET[idx];
    }
```

Comment: shouldn't it be 
if(idx==0)
return next(password.substring(0, password.length() )) + ALPHABET[0]; ?

Comment: No, substring() excludes the last char, if you use the length, you are index + 1, and thus will receive the whole string, but we need the prefix (all but the last char). So we need to reduce by one.

Comment: Thanks but i need a recursive method... 
Without any loops... or arrays... your answer has an array and a while loop..

Comment: It is left to you as an exercise to replace the while with a recursive call to findPassword.

Comment: but next(); has an array and it uses String methods like nextChar();
maybe it has somthing to do with ascii, I love to code... but im just broke...
Im not even sure im in the right path.. because String is an immutable class...i tried may ways...

Comment: the array used in `next()` is used to define the alphabet for the password. If you want to avoid it, replace it with a `String` and access it using `charAt` instead of `ALPHABET[idx]`. The array is just more concise. The immutability of String is completely irrelevant here, because `next()` returns a new `String` based on the previous one. I give you a findPasswordRecursive() method to eliminate the `while` but be aware, that recursion in this case means you will build a stack depth in the amount of passwords tried. 3 combinations, 3 recursions. 24 characters in alphabet -> (24^4)-1 recursions

Comment: I suggest you debug the code and add some log messages to it to understand what is going on.

Comment: oh, nextChar is a variable, not a method

Comment: havnt gone... just try still to understand it... but i guese its my problem...
I tried to use your code and modified it.. but it went wrong...
I can only overload with methods.. cant use other methods... ill give it couple more trys... thanks anyway for your time thst

Comment: I suggest you add a new question with the code you have tried, then we can have a look again.

Comment: thst, it's not taken for granted, I really thank you!
I really struggled understanding your code, Im sure your answer is right, 
I struggled converting the class to method/s with one signature(overload), 
plus, adding parameters. 

I couldnt even understand how its done with the arrays,
Maybe Ill understand it as a method and not as a class.
If you could make it as a method 
and not as a Class it would be great! 
Just this thing.. Leave the dirty work for me:
(making it with one signature and converting the array to a string, using charAt();)
Thank again!

Comment: My goal is detailed above, 
but thats just so you can see the full picture:
(again, Not asking to solve the whole problem, just to convert it to a method)

Password is Class 
Password p: is an object that is constructed by the Class,
It stores the random password in its attribute as a String.
I have 2 methods of this object: 
1. p.isPassword(String str); returns true if it is the right password
2. p.getPassword(); returns the password, just to check if im right cant use it in the method

Comment: basicly, I need to write a method called: 

String findPassword(Password p, int length): Returns a string of the right Password
so the only thing I have is the object, and the lenght of the password.

- "findPassword()" is the only signature I can use, Although I can use overload,
  sorry if I use the wrong syntax.
- This and all other methods have to be a recursive.
- If I want to use class String, i can only use: charAt, equals, length, substring.